# Skimage Region Adjacency Graph (RAG) from quickshift segmentation

Tags: python, python-2.7, classification, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I'm trying to create a Region Adjacency Graph from after segmenting an image using the tools in the `Skimage` package. Using the examples in the documentation I can segment an image using SLIC and create the RAG successfully.

```py
from skimage import data
from skimage import segmentation
from skimage.future import graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Load Image
img = data.coffee()

#Segment image
labels = segmentation.slic(img, compactness=30, n_segments=800)
#Create RAG
g = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels)
#Draw RAG
gplt = graph.draw_rag(labels, g, img)
plt.imshow(gplt)
```

[image: Successful RAG]

However, if I use either `segmentation.quickshift` or `segmentation.felzenszwalb` to segment the image and then create the RAG, I get an error at `draw_rag()`.

```py
labels = segmentation.quickshift(img, kernel_size=5, max_dist=5, ratio=0.5)
g = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels)
gplt = graph.draw_rag(labels, g, img)

labels = segmentation.felzenszwalb(img, scale=100, sigma=0.5, min_size=50)
g = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels)
gplt = graph.draw_rag(labels, g, img)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3032, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-c0784622a6c7>", line 1, in <module>
    gplt = graph.draw_rag(labels, g, img)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\future\graph\rag.py", line 429, in draw_rag
    out[circle] = node_color
IndexError: index 600 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 600
```

The documentation seems to suggest that RAG methods should be compatible with segments from any of these methods, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, there's a bug, or RAG can only be used with the SLIC segmentation method. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this was an issue in `Skimage 0.11.2` but is fixed in version `0.12.3`.